# How to convert a yii2 queryString to queryParams

Tags: php, search, parameters, yii2

I want to pass yii2 query params to an api.My js code is like

```
function doInBackground(){
      var params=<?=\Yii::$app->request->getQueryString()?>;
       $.get('car/get-map-data',
          {
           "params":params
      },
      function(data){
        if(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }); 
    }
```

And i am getting this search params as string in the server like

```
"CarSearch%5Bcity_id%5D=&CarSearch%5Bmotor_category%5D=9&drp-make%5B%5D=3&CarSearch%5Bdrp_make%5D=%2C3&CarSearch%5Bdrp_model%5D=&CarSearch%5Bmakes%5D=%22%2C3%22&CarSearch%5Bmodels%5D=&CarSearch%5Bprice_start%5D=&CarSearch%5Bprice_end%5D=&CarSearch%5Byear_start%5D=&CarSearch%5Byear_end%5D=&CarSearch%5Bkm_start%5D=&CarSearch%5Bkm_end%5D=&CarSearch%5Buser_location%5D=&CarSearch%5Blat%5D=0.0&CarSearch%5Blong%5D=0.0&CarSearch%5Bradius%5D=1000000000&CarSearch%5Btitle%5D="
```

And my controller action is

```
$params=Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
$dataProvider=$searchModel->search($params);
```

But i want the above parameter string in the format of params array to load for searching.How can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Above all you should have quotes around `<?=\Yii::$app->request->getQueryString()?>;` as you are not returning an object but a string, but what you want is different.

You should use the `Yii::$app->request->queryParams` and convert it to json object first

```
params = <?=\yii\helpers\Json::encode(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);?>
```

and just pass that variable without any outer parenthesis like

```
$.get('car/get-map-data',params,
  function(data){
    if(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This will send the request like

http://youdomain/car/get-map-data?param1=value1&param2=value2

Your complete code should look like

```
function doInBackground() {
    var params = <?=\yii\helpers\Json::encode(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);?>;
    $.get('car/get-map-data', params,
        function (data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    );
}
```